# Is there a way to hide label elements when the placeholder attribute is supported?

Tags: css, html

I would like the use the placeholder attribute instead of labels in my webpages, but I need to hide the labels when placeholders are supported.  Is this possible with only CSS?

Ideally, I like the equivalent of

label + input {
display: none;
}
-->

Answer (score 2):

You'd probably need to use [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) to detect placeholder support and then hide the labels. You'd need JavaScript though.

I'm not aware of another way, but others might be.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with CSS. There is no support for "parent selectors" and there most likely never will be.

If you don't want to use Modernizer, here's a simple test to run with JS:

```
if (("placeholder" in document.createElement("input"))) {
//placeholder is supported, so hide your label elements or whatever
}
```

Comment: I didn't see anyway without JavaScript, but I want support phones that don't have JavaScript.

Comment: I would have thought that if the phone doesn't support JavaScript, it's unlikely to support CSS!